# how to fix attempt to index nil with 'character' roblox number 2

Tags: lua, roblox

So to add on when the person who gave me an answer told me to change the line of code since i was using local script, it then said `Players.username.PlayerGui.replicated:24: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'` Here is more of the code in the script:

```
local Character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()
local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
local Camera = workspace:WaitForChild("Camera")
local BowModel = script:WaitForChild("Shard Bow"):Clone()
local Humanoid = Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
local animator = Humanoid:FindFirstChildOfClass("Animator")
script["Shard Bow"]:Destroy()
print(Animations:WaitForChild("BowWindup"))
local WindupAnimation = AnimModule.LoadSequence(Animations:WaitForChild("BowWindup"),Character)
local FireAnimation = AnimModule.LoadSequence(Animations:WaitForChild("BowFire"),Character)
local LaunchSound = script:WaitForChild("BowLaunch"):Clone()
local ExplosionSound = script:WaitForChild("BowHit"):Clone()
local ExplosionPart = script:WaitForChild("Explosion"):Clone()
script.BowLaunch:Destroy()
script.BowHit:Destroy()
if Player == LocalPlayer then
    Mouse = LocalPlayer:GetMouse()
end
```

Comment: sorry i am new here

Comment: Since you didn't included the line numbers I can't say which variable, but one of those (Character, workspace, script, Animations) you try to call `WaitForChild` on is nil. Make sure it is not.

Comment: as with your last post you're attempting to index a nil value. please don't ask multiple times about the same problem just because the variable names are different. you need to learn to abstract error messages from your code if you're searching for solution.

Comment: thank you for the help i am going to learn about nil values